# Preconnect using http.Client in golang

Tags: go, http

So basically I need to make a multitude of HTTP Requests to an endpoint. I can use `http.Client` for this purpose.

I know that making multiple HTTP Requests to the same endpoint using the `http.Client` will likely use a single TCP connection. However I have an use case for warming up the connection first.

I am wondering if there is any way for me to Dial the endpoint in advance so that the subsequent HTTP Request will reuse the connection and does not have to go through the TLS handshake.

I have the following

```golang
    dialer := &net.Dialer{
        Timeout:   30 * time.Second,
        KeepAlive: 30 * time.Second,
    }
    tlsDialer := &tls.Dialer{
        NetDialer: dialer,
        Config:    &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
    }

    transport := &http.Transport{
        DialTLSContext: func(ctx context.Context, network string, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
            fmt.Printf("DialTLSContext called %s %s\n", network, addr)
            return tlsDialer.DialContext(ctx, network, addr)
        },
    }

    client := &http.Client{
        Transport: transport,
    }
```

I can then Dial the underlying `Transport` this way:

```golang
    ctx := context.Background()
    transport.DialTLSContext(ctx, "tcp", "endpoint:443")
```

However when I do the actual request I find that `DialTLSContext` is invoked twice.
The reason for that is that my Dial is not going through the book-keeping of `http.Transport` which keeps an internal map of `scheme`,`endpoints` to `connections`. Is there any way to do that kind of `Dial` in a way that is intertwined with `http.Transport` mechanism?

Comment: Just make a simple request, like HEAD some endpoint. If you connect to a server, it’s waiting for you to send something, so it’s going to block waiting on that connection or just hang up.

Comment: That would work. So does that mean that there is no way from the public facing API to warm up the connection in the fashion I was describing in above?

Comment: There is not a public facing API to add a connection to the transport's pool.